# Copy File permission from One folder to other using Powershell

Tags: powershell, acl

I want to copy all the users/Groups from a NAS path which is DEV environment to UAT NAS path which have same folder structure using Powershell. I am using Powershell ver 5.1.
I tried to do using the following command :

`$acl = (Get-Item $prod_path).GetAccessControl('Access')`

`$acl  | Set-Acl -Path $non_prod_path`

```
try {
    foreach ($usr in ($prod_acl.access | where { $_.IsInherited -eq $True -and $_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow' })) {
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
            $usr.IdentityReference,
            "Read",
            $usr.InheritanceFlags,
            $usr.PropagationFlags,
            $usr.AccessControlType
        )

        # Calling SetAccessRule() is like calling Remove() then Add()
        $prod_acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    }
    (Get-Item $non_prod_path).SetAccessControl($prod_acl)
} catch { continue }
```

But its giving me an error saying **Set-Acl : The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege 
which is required for this operation.**. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting permissions on a windows fileshare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611103/setting-permissions-on-a-windows-fileshare)

Comment: Setting ACLs requires some level of permission, so make sure the user you're running this script as has permission to actually do the operation.

Comment: @boxdog, yes that answered my part of the question.

Comment: @boxdog, yes that answered my part of the question.
I am trying to copy file permission from one NAS path to other.  I used a part of the logic mentioned in that url, which helps me in adding the ACL permission on top of the existing one. I have updated my code tried so far. How to remove the existing unwanted group?

Comment: @FoxDeploy I do have all the required permission for this operation.

Comment: PowerShell has a concept of running as Administrator, you must be running as an admin in addition to also the NTFS permissions to complete the operation.

Comment: Check the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611103/setting-permissions-on-a-windows-fileshare?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @FoxDeploy The top answered helped me for a part of my question, not the complete answer. I want to remove the existing ACL permission from the destination path, which is not happening.